# How did Trinity know that Choi would invite Neo to the club?

Tags: the-matrix

Related to [How did Trinity know that Neo would see a white rabbit (to follow)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128325/how-did-trinity-know-that-neo-would-see-a-white-rabbit-to-follow), how did she know that Choi (boyfriend of Du Jour, the girl with the tattoo) would invite Neo to the club?

Neo is asleep at his computer.  All Trinity knows is that Choi and Du Jour are going to Neo's apartment to buy something on their way to a nightclub.  Choi invites Neo on a spur-of-the-moment impulse, not as part of a plan he devised ahead of time.

> CHOI
>   Something wrong, man? You look a little whiter than usual.
>
> NEO
>   My computer... it...  You ever have that feeling where you're not sure if you're awake or still dreaming?
>
> CHOI
>   All the time. It's called mescaline.  It's the only way to fly.  **Hey, it just sounds to me like, y'know, you need to unplug, man. Y'know? Get some R&R? What do you think, Dujour?  should we take him with us?**
>
> DUJOUR
>   **Definitely.**
>
> NEO
>   **I can't. I have to work tomorrow.**
>
> DUJOUR
>   **Come on. It'll be fun. I promise.**
>
> NEO
>   Yeah. Sure.  I'll go.

For Neo to go with Choi, Du Jour, and [the other weirdos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whnVq.jpg), several things needed to happen:

- Neo has to wake up for no apparent reason when the words "Wake up, Neo" appeared (almost silently) on his screen.
- [Neo has to see the white rabbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128325/how-did-trinity-know-that-neo-would-see-a-white-rabbit-to-follow) and make the mental connection to the messages he received from an anonymous hacker.
- The weirdos who came to buy stuff from him have randomly decide to invite him to the club where Trinity will meet him<sup>1</sup>.
- Neo has to accept the invitation<sup>1</sup>, despite the facts that:

  1. It is late at night
  2. He was just sound asleep
  3. He doesn't appear to be personal friends with the weirdos
  4. He has to be at work in a few hours
  5. Instead of freaking out because someone is spying on him, knows about his felonious behavior, and has hacked into his computer, Neo has to obey his anonymous stalker and ignore the fact that this person could get him arrested<sup>2</sup>.

Let's assume that Neo is so curious about the mysterious "Matrix" that he'd accept the invitation to the club after seeing the tattoo, and that Trinity knows this.  We'll also assume that Trinity was certain that Neo would see the tattoo and make the mental connection to her message.

**We're still faced with the problem of how Trinity could be sure that the weirdos would invite Neo to the club.**

### How did Trinity know that Choi would invite Neo to the club?

---

<sup>1</sup>*Or alternatively, Neo has to invite himself, and the weirdos have to let him come along.*

<sup>2</sup>*Neo was asleep, and his computer was scanning through news stories about Morpheus, when the screen went black and a message from an unidentified person appeared - in other words, someone hacked his computer.  He regularly uses this computer to commit felonies.  The person who hacked his computer knows that a group of weirdos was about to knock on his door to buy illegal programs or code or whatever it was;  he or she also knew that one of the weirdos had a tattoo of a white rabbit on her shoulder - in other words, whoever sent the messages is spying on Neo's apartment building right now, and knows that he has just committed another crime.  If I were him, I would be destroying my computer and any other evidence of my criminal activity, not going clubbing with weirdos.*

Comment: Although this is a good question, I'm faced with the fact that my answer makes it a dupe.

Comment: @Richard - Then why did you answer this one?  Delete your answer here, and I'll close this as a dupe.  Seems fair to me.

Comment: Done and Done :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think she knew anything about the invitation, or could have foreseen it in any way. The message simply said "Follow the white rabbit".

When the discussion with the weirdos happened, Neo was reluctant at first, but as soon as he saw the tattoo, he immediately flipped on his decision.

> NEO
> I can't. I have to work tomorrow.
>
> DUJOUR
> Come on. It'll be fun. I promise.

At this point, Neo notices the tattoo

> NEO
> Yeah. Sure. I'll go.

I don't think a passing remark of "It'll be fun" would convince anyone, especially not a shut-in, cyber hacker that has work the next day.

As you mentioned in your question,

> All Trinity knows is that Choi and Du Jour are going to Neo's apartment to buy something on their way to a nightclub.

She knows the group is going to a nightclub (and it's implied she knows which one, as it is never specified in the dialogue), so she knows the meeting place. She's given Neo the bait, and now she just has to rely on him showing up.

- There's nothing stopping Neo from declining the invite, even after he sees the tattoo
- There's nothing stopping him from inviting himself
- There's nothing stopping him simply following them, even uninvited

making the "invitation" redundant.